# Junits test case - HSQLDB count(...) over (partition ... order by ...)

Tags: sql, junit, hsqldb, window-functions

I'm trying to calculate the count based on id and my query is working fine with Oracle.

When I try to execute in JUNITS with the same query it throwing "unexpected token: ( ". The line which throws error mentioned below,

```
COUNT(tab1.ID) OVER (partition by tab2.ID order by tab2.ID) as CountSample"
```

How can I overcome this error by rewriting the query.

Answer (score 1):

This type of query, with OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY), is not supported by HSQLDB. HyperXtremeSQL (http://hyperxtreme.co.uk) is a database engine based on HSQLDB with extended SQL syntax that supports the query.